# Reading in RouteValues to Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routevalues

so I have a Url Action

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","Teacher", new { createAndAssign = true, teacherID = Model.AccountID })">Create new teacher & assign to account.</a>
```

That passes in two routeValues: createAndAssign, and teacherID.

Now when I go to my Teacher/Create page, my URL is like so:

```
.../Teacher/Create?createAndAssign=True&teacherID=ea817321-5633-4fdc-b388-5dba2c4a728e
```

Which is good, I want this. Now when I POST to create my teacher, how do I grab createAndAssign and teacherID value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Querystring value in a hidden variables in the form and render in your GET action method and accept that in your POST action method.

View rendered by your `GET` Action

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 //Other form elements also
  @Html.Hidden("teacher",@Request.QueryString["teacherID"] as string)
  @Html.Hidden("createAndAssign",@Request.QueryString["createAndAssign"] 
                                                                    as string)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and now have a `teacher` parameter and createAndAssign parameter in your `HttpPost` action method so that it will be available when you submit the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string teacher,string createAndAssign)
{
     //Save and Redirect      
}
```

**If your view is strongly typed** (which is my personal preference), it is quite easy,

```
public ActionResult GET(string teacherID,string createdAndAssing)
{
   var yourVMObject=new YourViewModel();
   yourVMObject.TeacherID=teacherID;
   yourVMObject.CreateAndAssign=createdAndAssing;
   return View(createdAndAssing);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view,

```
@model YourViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 //Other form elements also
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.TeacherID)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.CreateAndAssign)                                     
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your `POST` action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel model)
{
     //look for model.TeacherID
     //Save and Redirect      
}
```

Comment: No clue why I didn't think of using a viewModel, as I'm using a bunch in other areas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value from the query string or as params of the controller like

```
var x =Request.QueryString["createAndAssign"];
```

or

```
public ActionResult Create(bool createAndAssign, string teacherID){


 return View();
}
```

Comment: Alright, and to get them to work in HttpPost, I just store them in a @Html.Hidden() ?

Comment: Not in MVC, thats totally against what its about.

Comment: Using the Request.QueryString dictionary to obtain route values is